# How to get a datatype of class by name?

Tags: c#

`InputData` is a class with a bunch of properties, and I am trying to dynamically create columns for them in a datatable. `varNames` is the list of properties that exist in the `InputData` class.

```
foreach(var item in varNames)
    m_dt.Columns.Add(item, typeof(InputData).GetProperties().Where(prop=> prop.Name == item).Select(prop=>prop.GetType()).ElementAt(0));
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Type test = typeof(InputData).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.Name == item).ElementAt(0).PropertyType;
```